# date(now) only working with time 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to get the number of rows where the date is today. Its working like this but only if the time is `00:00:00` so if i change the time to for example `2016-04-25 05:30:30` its not counting that row for some reason.

```
$result16  = $dbhandle->query("SELECT * FROM email  WHERE signoff = DATE(NOW() )");
$row_cnt16 = $result16->num_rows;
```

What should I do to fix this?

```
Table information:
signoff = varchar(250)
```

**Outputs:**

if date is `2016-04-25 00:00:00` the output is `2`

if the date is `2016-04-25 05:04:00` output is `1`

Comment: You can try this : `SELECT * FROM email  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(signoff,'%Y-%m-%d') = DATE(NOW())`

Comment: why use `varchar` but not `date` or `datetime` format for collumn in table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM email 
WHERE signoff BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND  DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer its working and I think i'm using this one since i also  need to make this with an interval of 7 days

Answer (score 1):

First change your data type of `signoff` to `datetime`.

Then use this query

```
SELECT * FROM email  
WHERE date(signoff) = DATE(CURDATE())
```

If speed is an issue you can use

```
SELECT * FROM email  
WHERE signoff >= curdate()
  AND signoff < curdate() + interval 1 day
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this by adding Date to the signoff

```
$result16 = $dbhandle->query("SELECT * FROM email  WHERE DATE(signoff) = DATE(NOW() )");
```

Comment: i will but i can't yet 5 minutes ;)

Comment: @marijn - to use DATE(signoff) is not the best way. MySQL must calculate each row to findout the selected ROW. (FULL TABLE SCAN)